# Entering data in a table

Tags: list-manipulation

This following table works nicely --- sorry for the french

```
l = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
per = Permutations[l];
info = Table[
   StringJoin[Riffle[per[[i]], {"\[Succeeds]"}]], {i, 1, Length[per]}];
propd = Table[info[[i]], {i, 1, Length[per]/6}, {j, 1, 6}];
enterdata = 
  Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, 
    InputField[Dynamic[propd[[i, j]]], FieldSize -> 11, 
     Background -> LightGray]], {i, 1, Length[per]/6}, {j, 1, 6}];
{{Style["Substituer le nombre d'agents qui ont les préférences \
indiquées.", Red]}, {Style[
    "(Ce nombre est automatiquement substitué et il n'est pas \
nécessaire de compiler la commande."]},
  {Style["Le nom du vecteur ainsi construit est propd)"]}, \
{enterdata}} // TableForm
```

I dont Know how

1) to center the text

2) to add a command which centers the table in the notebook

3) that the modification be on the variable propd after to have been Flatten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add option `Alignment -> Center` to the `InputFields` to center the text in them, and for the table itself I recommend using `Grid` also with `Alignment -> Center`.  I'm not really sure what you mean by 3) but if you are asking how to get the changes to *propd*, the `InputField` dynamically updates the value of *propd*.  My modifications to your code look like this:

```
l = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
per = Permutations[l];
info = Table[
   StringJoin[Riffle[per[[i]], {"\[Succeeds]"}]], {i, 1, Length[per]}];
propd = Table[info[[i]], {i, 1, Length[per]/6}, {j, 1, 6}];
enterdata = Table[
   With[
    {i = i, j = j},
    InputField[Dynamic[propd[[i, j]]], FieldSize -> 11, 
     Background -> LightGray, Alignment -> Center]
    ],
   {i, 1, Length[per]/6},
   {j, 1, 6}
   ];
Grid[
 Join[
  {
   {Style[
     "Substituer le nombre d'agents qui ont les préférences \
indiquées.", Red], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
    SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
   {Style[
     "(Ce nombre est automatiquement substitué et il n'est pas \
nécessaire de compiler la commande."], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
    SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
   {Style["Le nom du vecteur ainsi construit est propd)"], 
    SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}
   },
  enterdata
  ],
 Alignment -> Center
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks lowriniak. In what concerns 3), I need a vector not a matrix so the lines must be concatenated in one unique.

Comment: For that you could make a new variable `propdCat := Flatten[propd]` (you can flatten to whatever level is needed.  Alternatively you could have a button that changes `propd` to whatever shape you need (note that this will then break your input grid). The button code would be something like `Button[ "Flatten propd", propd = Flatten[propd]]`

Comment: Good Idea! Thanks